# Odoo Installation Using custom .sh file In Google Compute Engine VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, virtualhost, odoo-10

I m using Google Compute engine, Already I configured VM Instance using PHP wesites.That one running successfully.

I want to install [ODOO](https://www.odoo.com/page/download). Using Windows OS  installed odoo successfully, Working all Apps.

I want Odoo Apps in My Google Compute engine. So, I prepared one custom installation .sh file.Filename **odoo_install.sh**

So I gave odoo_install.sh as executable file  in my SSH.

```
$sudo chmod +x odoo_install.sh


$ vi odoo_install.sh

#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# Script for installing Odoo V9 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (could be used for other version too)
# Author: Yenthe Van Ginneken
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This script will install Odoo on your Ubuntu 14.04 server. It can install multiple Odoo instances
# in one Ubuntu because of the different xmlrpc_ports
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Make a new file:
# sudo nano odoo-install.sh
# Place this content in it and then make the file executable:
# sudo chmod +x odoo-install.sh
# Execute the script to install Odoo:
# ./odoo-install
################################################################################
##fixed parameters
#odoo
OE_USER="odoo"
OE_HOME="/$OE_USER"
OE_HOME_EXT="/$OE_USER/${OE_USER}-server"
#The default port where this Odoo instance will run under (provided you use the command -c in the terminal)
#Set to true if you want to install it, false if you don't need it or have it already installed.
INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF="True"
#Set the default Odoo port (you still have to use -c /etc/odoo-server.conf for example to use this.)
OE_PORT="8069"
#Choose the Odoo version which you want to install. For example: 9.0, 8.0, 7.0 or saas-6. When using 'trunk' the master version will be installed.
#IMPORTANT! This script contains extra libraries that are specifically needed for Odoo 9.0
OE_VERSION="9.0"
#set the superadmin password
OE_SUPERADMIN="admin"
OE_CONFIG="${OE_USER}-server"
##
###  WKHTMLTOPDF download links
## === Ubuntu Trusty x64 & x32 === (for other distributions please replace these two links,
## in order to have correct version of wkhtmltox installed, for a danger note refer to
## https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html#deb ):
WKHTMLTOX_X64=https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
WKHTMLTOX_X32=https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-i386.deb
#--------------------------------------------------
# Update Server
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Update Server ----"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y





#--------------------------------------------------
# Install PostgreSQL Server
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Install PostgreSQL Server ----"
sudo apt-get install postgresql -y
echo -e "\n---- Creating the ODOO PostgreSQL User  ----"
sudo su - postgres -c "createuser -s $OE_USER" 2> /dev/null || true
#--------------------------------------------------
# Install Dependencies
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Install tool packages ----"
sudo apt-get install wget subversion git bzr bzrtools python-pip gdebi-core -y
echo -e "\n---- Install python packages ----"
sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-feedparser python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-openid python-psycopg2 python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing python-r
eportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-vatnumber python-vobject python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi python-docutils python-psutil python-mock python-unittest2 python-jinja
2 python-pypdf python-decorator python-requests python-passlib python-pil -y
echo -e "\n---- Install python libraries ----"
sudo pip install gdata psycogreen ofxparse flanker
echo -e "\n--- Install other required packages"
sudo apt-get install node-clean-css -y
sudo apt-get install node-less -y
sudo apt-get install python-gevent -y
echo -e "\n--- Create symlink for node"
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
#--------------------------------------------------
# Install Wkhtmltopdf if needed
#--------------------------------------------------
if [ $INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF = "True" ]; then
echo -e "\n---- Install wkhtml and place shortcuts on correct place for ODOO 9 ----"
#pick up correct one from x64 & x32 versions:
if [ "`getconf LONG_BIT`" == "64" ];then
_url=$WKHTMLTOX_X64
else
_url=$WKHTMLTOX_X32
fi
sudo wget $_url
sudo gdebi --n `basename $_url`
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
else
echo "Wkhtmltopdf isn't installed due to the choice of the user!"
fi



echo -e "\n---- Create ODOO system user ----"
sudo adduser --system --quiet --shell=/bin/bash --home=$OE_HOME --gecos 'ODOO' --group $OE_USER
#The user should also be added to the sudo'ers group.
sudo adduser $OE_USER sudo
echo -e "\n---- Create Log directory ----"
sudo mkdir /var/log/$OE_USER
sudo chown $OE_USER:$OE_USER /var/log/$OE_USER
#--------------------------------------------------
# Install ODOO
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n==== Installing ODOO Server ===="
sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch $OE_VERSION https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo $OE_HOME_EXT/
echo -e "\n---- Create custom module directory ----"
sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/enterprise"
sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/enterprise/addons"
echo -e "\n---- Adding Enterprise code under $OE_HOME/enterprise/addons ----"
sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch $OE_VERSION https://www.github.com/odoo/enterprise "$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons"
echo -e "\n---- Installing Enterprise specific libraries ----"
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
sudo npm install -g less
sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
echo -e "\n---- Setting permissions on home folder ----"
sudo chown -R $OE_USER:$OE_USER $OE_HOME/*
echo -e "* Create server config file"
sudo cp $OE_HOME_EXT/debian/openerp-server.conf /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo chown $OE_USER:$OE_USER /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo chmod 640 /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
echo -e "* Change server config file"
sudo sed -i s/"db_user = .*"/"db_user = $OE_USER"/g /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo sed -i s/"; admin_passwd.*"/"admin_passwd = $OE_SUPERADMIN"/g /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo su root -c "echo 'logfile = /var/log/$OE_USER/$OE_CONFIG$1.log' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
sudo su root -c "echo 'addons_path=$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons,$OE_HOME_EXT/addons' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
echo -e "* Create startup file"
sudo su root -c "echo '#!/bin/sh' >> $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh"
sudo su root -c "echo 'sudo -u $OE_USER $OE_HOME_EXT/openerp-server --config=/etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf' >> $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh"
sudo chmod 755 $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh
#--------------------------------------------------
# Adding ODOO as a deamon (initscript)
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "* Create init file"


cat <<EOF > ~/$OE_CONFIG
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: $OE_CONFIG
# Required-Start: \$remote_fs \$syslog
# Required-Stop: \$remote_fs \$syslog
# Should-Start: \$network
# Should-Stop: \$network
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Enterprise Business Applications
# Description: ODOO Business Applications
### END INIT INFO
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=$OE_HOME_EXT/openerp-server
NAME=$OE_CONFIG
DESC=$OE_CONFIG
# Specify the user name (Default: odoo).
USER=$OE_USER
# Specify an alternate config file (Default: /etc/openerp-server.conf).
CONFIGFILE="/etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
# pidfile
PIDFILE=/var/run/\${NAME}.pid
# Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.
DAEMON_OPTS="-c \$CONFIGFILE"
[ -x \$DAEMON ] || exit 0
[ -f \$CONFIGFILE ] || exit 0
checkpid() {
[ -f \$PIDFILE ] || return 1
pid=\`cat \$PIDFILE\`
[ -d /proc/\$pid ] && return 0
return 1
}
case "\${1}" in
start)
echo -n "Starting \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--chuid \$USER --background --make-pidfile \
--exec \$DAEMON -- \$DAEMON_OPTS
echo "\${NAME}."
;;
stop)
echo -n "Stopping \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--oknodo
echo "\${NAME}."
;;
restart|force-reload)


echo -n "Restarting \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--oknodo
sleep 1
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--chuid \$USER --background --make-pidfile \
--exec \$DAEMON -- \$DAEMON_OPTS
echo "\${NAME}."
;;
*)
N=/etc/init.d/\$NAME
echo "Usage: \$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
EOF
echo -e "* Security Init File"
sudo mv ~/$OE_CONFIG /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
sudo chown root: /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
echo -e "* Change default xmlrpc port"
sudo su root -c "echo 'xmlrpc_port = $OE_PORT' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
echo -e "* Start ODOO on Startup"
sudo update-rc.d $OE_CONFIG defaults
echo -e "* Starting Odoo Service"
sudo su root -c "/etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG start"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Done! The Odoo server is up and running. Specifications:"
echo "Port: $OE_PORT"
echo "User service: $OE_USER"
echo "User PostgreSQL: $OE_USER"
echo "Code location: $OE_USER"
echo "Addons folder: $OE_USER/$OE_CONFIG/addons/"
echo "Start Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG start"
echo "Stop Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG stop"
echo "Restart Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG restart"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
```

$./odoo_install.sh

After execute odoo_install.sh

I got the below

```
Create custom module directory 
----mkdir: cannot create directory `/odoo/custom': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/odoo/custom/addons': No such file or directory

---- Setting permissions on home folder ----
    * Create server config file
    * Creating server config file
    * Create startup file
    * Create init file
    * Security Init File
    * Start ODOO on Startupupdate-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing

* Starting Odoo ServiceStarting odoo-server: odoo-server.-----------------------------------------------------------Done! 
The Odoo server is up and running. 

Specifications:Port: 8069
User service: odoo
User PostgreSQL: odoo
Code location: odoo
Addons folder: odoo/odoo-server/addons/Start 
Odoo service: sudo service odoo-server start
Stop Odoo service: sudo service odoo-server stop
Restart Odoo service: sudo service odoo-server restart----
```

I configured this `/etc/odoo-server.conf` file with port

```
options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path=/odoo/odoo-server/addons,/odoo/custom/addons
xmlrpc_port = 8070
```

After this I tried to start odoo server, odoo-server not started.
I don't know what I missed in this installation.

Plz help me to solve this,
If any other steps to install odoo server and Apps in Google Compute Engine,
Plz let me know.

I appreciate those who help to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not start the odoo server because in config file you have this line `addons_path=/odoo/odoo-server/addons,/odoo/custom/addons`, but your odoo installation script was unable to create `/odoo/custom/addons` directory for lack of permission, but that directory is listed as addons directory. Because that directory doesn't even exists, odoo server is unable to start.

Also, when failing to start the odoo service, you should provide the log file, or we are unable to provide support why your server is failing to start.

Comment: see the log... the server actually starts, but most likely it has no modules.

Comment: see my answer, it doesn't matter if the directory contains modules or empty. once listed in `addons_path`, that directory must exist. or `odoo-bin` will throw error in the begining. @MartinZeitler

Comment: Thanks, Martin Zeitler and arryph. I will recheck and let you know the status

Comment: Installation log details  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZK9F9JdJb1dW6rooPuKt8IJLd7dPFqwUlRqtC3R01QM/edit#gid=0,  But i can't see the log file root@lamp-bafs:/# tail -f /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
tail: cannot open `/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log' for reading: No such file or directory. Plz help me, What I missed here. thanks arryph

Comment: as Zeitler and I both suggested, your server can't startup because `/odoo/custom/addons` directory was not created by the script but is added in `config`, that's why your server can't start. Either you create the directory manually or edit `odoo-server.conf` file and remove that direcotry from `addons_path` list and you should be good to go.

Comment: I created the folder manually /odoo/custom/addons. Here is the installation Log after created the addons folder. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZK9F9JdJb1dW6rooPuKt8IJLd7dPFqwUlRqtC3R01QM/edit#gid=1033421022, refer the Log 2 sheet. Also removed the odoo/custom/addons from odoo-server.conf. But same result only I got.

Comment: None of the required python package's is installed, you are running command with sudo permission, even on root shell.

Comment: python 3 not installed in my VM Debian 7. I want to Odoo in Google Compute Engine, Could you plz help me is there any alternate installation? If yes, Plz let me know the details.

Comment: Sure, there are many way's to configure odoo server, I can sure help you out. What kind of setup do you want? Let me know the details.

Comment: @arryph, I need Odoo server with all apps in my GCE VM instance Debian 7.Plz let me give the steps/ documents to configure Odoo applications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187974/discussion-between-arryph-and-sattanathan).

Answer (score 1):

the script appears a little crappy, hence it installs into the root `/`, instead of `/home` (or `/opt`). better change `OE_HOME="/$OE_USER"` to `OE_HOME="/home/$OE_USER"` ...in order not to create a mess. `sudo rm -R /odoo` should remove the previous installation attempt, except the postgres user.

or at least run `sudo mkdir -p /odoo/custom/addons && chown -R odoo:odoo /odoo/custom` before the installation, then it should be able to install the custom modules.

Comment: I changed as per your instruction and tried the odoo installation, here is the odoo installation https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZK9F9JdJb1dW6rooPuKt8IJLd7dPFqwUlRqtC3R01QM/edit#gid=0, But Same result only, http://my-ipaddress:8069 not opening, Plz help me thanks Martin Zeitler

Comment: @Sattanathan are you sure that `my-ipaddress` is the host-name of your server? dynamic `DNS` is useless for `GCP`; you'd need to assign an external IP address and open `tcp/8069` by tagging the instance with such a firewall-rule. else it could only be connected from the internal network, which would be rather useless for any kind of web-application.

Comment: @Zeitler my-ipaddress is my GCE external IP address.Also open tcp/8069 in VPC Network -->firewall rules. But my-ipaddress:8069 not opening